# How to eliminate performance details from Visual Studio 2019 build log Output Window

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, output-window

I think this is an *MSBuild* setting, but I am running from Visual Studio 2019.

How do I make the VS Output Window less cluttered by removing the 95 lines of *Target Performance Summary* time details?  (I'll enable it when I need to profile the build process - hopefully never.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Project Setting and check the value of Build Timing.  Change it to "No" can remove the Performance Summary at the end of Output window.
[image]

If it doesn't work you can go to Tools > Import and Export Settings to Reset all settings.
[image]

Comment: The *Build Timing: No* answer worked as desired.  I still get start time and the build duration, but not the long list of  task timings.